# Enum data type in EMF

Tags: eclipse-emf

How to get information about an attribute of enum type?

I have an `EClass` with an attribute which is type of enum. I know you can use the following code to determine the type of an attribute

```
EDataType type = attr.getEAttributeType();
if (type == EcorePackage.Literals.EINT);
//do something
if (type == EcorePackage.Literals.EENUM);
// do something
```

But the line (`type == EcorePackage.Literals.EENUM`) doesn't work, thus I am wondering how to determine an attribute is type of eEnum, given any Ecore metamodels.

Answer (score 0):

For enumerated types you could use either of:

```
type instanceof EEnum
type.eClass() == EcorePackage.eINSTANCE.getEEnum()
```